# Makefile "nothing to be done"

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to compile c++ using a the following make file...

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -O2
OBJECTS = WavFileTool.o WavFile.o

WavFileTool.exe : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o wavfiletool.exe

WavFileTool.o : WavFileTool.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c WavFileTool.cpp

WavFile.o : WavFile.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c WavFile.cpp
```

But when I run this is just says "nothing to be done". I am a little confused. Based on the tutorials I read, I can not figure out what is wrong...

Comment: What you mean *But when I run this is just says "nothing to be done"*?

Comment: what command to you use to build it? `make WavFileTool.exe`?

Comment: Did you try `rm WavFileTool.exe` before running `make`?

Comment: Also, you should simply use `make` or `make WavFileTool.exe` rather than something like `make all` which many online tutorials may include, since you don't have an `all` target.

Comment: Check the modification times on the files. Is `WavFileTool.exe` newer than both .o and .cpp files? Are both .o files newer than their .cpp files? If so, `make` is working correctly.

Comment: Also, (assuming gnu make) you can omit some of the rules. Make has implicit rules for `.o` files from `.cpp` ones. And you're hijaking C variables such as `CC` and `CFLAGS`. The C++ equivalents (used by the implicit rules) are `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: Also, is your filesysyem case-insensitive? Because the target `WavFileTool.exe` is not the same as what the rule produces: `wavfiletool.exe`.

Comment: What's the modification times for WavFileTool.exe, WavFileTool.o, WavFileTool.o, WawFileTool.cpp, WavFile.cpp and the makefile?  Which implementation of `make` do you use by the way?

Comment: @juanchopanza That should not be the problem in this case, with case sensitive filesystem no WavFileTool.exe would have been produced and the opposite problem would occur (there would always WavFileTool.exe to be done).

Comment: @skyking: .exe implies Windows. So, yes, that's probably the problem.

Comment: @skyking Perhaps. But it is *a* problem. If I was sure it was *the* problem I would have posted an answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I misread, if its' case-*in*sensitive there's that problmen (if its case-sensitive it would be another problem).

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely due to you having case-insensitive file system and you don't match cases on filenames in the make file. Try changing the first rule to:

```
WavFileTool.exe : $(OBJECTS)     
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o WavFileTool.exe
```

If you don't have case sensitive file system you would likely to be seing the problem that WavFileTool.exe being rebuilt every-time regardless of the source being updated or not.

There's of course a third possibility, that you're using a file sensitive file system and having both a wavfiletool.exe file **and** a WavFileTool.exe file (where WavFileTool.exe is newer than any of the sources). I don't think windows would allow that though (and I would think you would find that odd anyway).

Answer (score 1):

As @skyking explained already, you are observing this issue because you had to type the same file names several times and made a mistake.

To prevent this class of errors resulting from having to type the same thing multiple times make has [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) and [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Intro).

I modified your makefile to:

1. Use automatic variables `$@`, `$<` and `$^` to refer to the rule output and inputs.
2. Use a pattern rule to build `.o` from `.cpp`.
3. Automatically generate header file dependencies.
4. Added `-Wall -Wextra` compiler flags to detect more errors at compile time for you.
5. Use `LDFLAGS` for linking, rather than `CFLAGS`.

---

```
CC = g++
LDFLAGS = -g
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -g -O2
OBJECTS = WavFileTool.o WavFile.o

WavFileTool.exe : $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^ 

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) -MP -MD -c $<

-include $(OBJECTS:%.o=%.d)
```

Answer (score 1):

I came upon the solution to my problem.

I was running....

```
make [my unique makefile name]
```

the problem resolved when I renamed the file to "makefile", and just rane the command "make".